# Is there a request form in Pokemon Go that I can request the design of clothing?

Tags: pokemon-go

For example, when I am at the beach, I would like myself be in Pokemon Go to wear swimming clothing. So, if I diving, I would like myself be in Pokemon Go to wear diving suit. However, currently, there is no swimming or diving clothing in Pokemon Go.

So, do Pokemon Go have a webpage that allows user to request clothing design?

Answer (score 5):

You could try asking on their [contact page here](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/). Select issue type as 'General Question'. Alternatively, you can try to contact them on [twitter](https://twitter.com/pokemongoapp) and hope that they reply you.

Do note that this would be a suggestion, and not a request as Niantic has no obligations to implement your request.